# Is there a positive opposite for Perfection?

Tags: antonyms

There most fitting opposite (IMO) for *perfection* is *imperfection*. This however does carry some negative connotation. What I would like to express is that imperfection is actually a good thing.

What word exists that means "not perfect" and at the same time conveys encouragement and acceptance?

**UPDATE**:
An example sentence would be: 
"Imperfection allows room for flexibility and adaptation." The context here is intelligent systems.

Comment: How would you use the word in a sentence?

Comment: How about *human*?

Comment: Something _perfect_ for purpose _A_ may still be flexible enough or adaptable to purpose _B_. Your requirement is still not clear.

Comment: If flexilibity and adaptation are *required*, then a perfect system would *have* them, and a system lacking them would *not* be perfect. So maybe 'perfection' wasn't the right word in the first place.

Comment: Why always the _one_ word request? 1) 'purposeful imperfection', 2) '[wabi-sabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wabi-sabi)'?

Comment: People these days talk about a thing being a _good enough_ solution. It communicates that the solution is practical but not perfect.

Comment: How about 'adequate' or 'adequacy'? This means  'good enough' but does not imply the impossibility of improvement.

Comment: Do you mean "fuzzy", as in "fuzzy logic"?

Comment: @jimm101 It does have a fuzzy connotation

Comment: What about 'improvability'?

Answer (score 2):

Many people describe imperfections, deficiencies, weaknesses, etc. as *opportunities for improvement*. The term is especially prevalent in quality management.

They do this "to express that imperfection is actually a good thing," looked at the right way.

Also as per your question, *opportunities for improvement* "means 'not perfect' and at the same time conveys encouragement and acceptance."

If you google *opportunity(ies) for improvement*, you'll get many hits, e.g.:

> [Opportunities for Improvement](http://www.baldrige21.com/BALDRIGE_GLOSSARY/BN/Opportunities_For_Improvement.html) - OFIs (Assessment Feedback Comments)
>   The term "opportunities for improvement (OFIs or OFI)" refers to
>   written assessment statements (comments) included in Baldrige
>   assessment reports (e.g., individual-, consensus-, and site
>   visit-level reports and Applicant Feedback reports) that describe
>   [Criteria] requirements that are not addressed (i.e., gaps) or that
>   could be more effectively addressed through process or illustrated
>   through results. [Baldrige Performance Excellence Program]

The term has much broader and less formal currency.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *perfection*/*imperfection* is the wrong set of words here. [Perfection](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/perfection) is defined as (OED):

> The condition, state, or quality of being free or as free as possible from all flaws or defects.

Arguably, the intelligent system which "allows room for flexibility and adaptation" would be more perfect than one that does not. In contrast, a word like [rigid](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rigid) seems to better fit your intended meaning:

> Unable to bend or be forced out of shape; not flexible.

Some antonyms might include: **lenient**, **tolerant**, **bending**, or **pliable**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in a sentence for a person, the phrase "warts and all" can be used.

e.g. Although not perfect, but you are good enough to be accepted warts and all.

If you mention the context, it will be easier to suggest words.